# Ionic-angular, how to get root directory of the SD card?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm using Ionic framework to do a file browser app, but only within the SD card. To access de SD card I'm using the [File](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) plugin with **File.externalRootDirectory**, and I retrieve from that it's list of directories. This is the code:

> ```
> constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private fileCtrl: File) {
>     this.goToDir("");
> }
>
> public goToDir(dir: string){
>     this.fileCtrl.listDir(this.fileCtrl.externalRootDirectory, dir).then(
>         (list) => {
>             this.loadList(list);
>         }
>     );
> }
>
> public loadList(list: any){
>     for (let i=0; i<list.length; i++)
>     {
>         console.log(list[i].fullPath);
>     }
>  }
> ```

This doesn't return the directories in my SD card, it's giving me the list of directories of the internal storage of the device (dirs = Android, DCIM, Downloads, etc).

I'm testing in Android 4.4 and 6.0 and I have Ionic and Cordova updated to the latest.

I'm new to Ionic and I fail to see what I'm doing wrong. It'll be really cool if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

> This doesn't return the directories in my SD card, it's giving me the list of directories of the internal storage of the device (dirs = Android, DCIM, Downloads, etc).

From this, I assume you are trying to access a physical external removable SD card (such as in a Samsung Galaxy S7) as opposed to the "internal SD card", as Android refers to it, which is actually internal memory.

For example, in Android 7.1, my physical external removable SD card path is `/storage/4975-1401/`.

Whereas my "internal" SD card path is `/storage/emulated/0/`.

`cordova-plugin-file` does not enable you to access the physical external removable SD card: for me `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory` returns `file:///storage/emulated/0/`.

However, you can use the [getExternalSdCardDetails()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#getexternalsdcarddetails) of [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) to retrieve the filepath to the physical external removable SD card:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getExternalSdCardDetails(function(details){
    details.forEach(function(detail){
        if(detail.type == "root"){
            cordova.file.externalSdCardRootDirectory = detail.filePath;
        }
    });
}, function(error){
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: You are right. I did a workaround by setting the root directory as the static root of my SdCard ("file:///storage/extSdCard"), and it worked, but your solution seems so much better. I'll try it when i have time. Thank you.